# Duplicate UART Input (BeagleBone, CPP, Linux)

Tags: c++, linux, beagleboneblack, uart

right now I'm playing around with a BeagleBone and some GPS Sensors. I receive my data via UART and can read the data in a cpp program.

The problem I'm having occurs if two seperate programs/threads read from the same UART the data read by Thread A is lost for Thread B.

Is there a way in Linux to duplicate/mirror an input device? So for example to create a /dev/ttyO1_copy?

Thanks for the help!